# How do I create an admin in Ruby On Rails using the Devise Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, rubygems

I am developing a rails application and am using a gem called devise to manage my users. I have created a new user called "Admin" but am unsure on how to change a user on the application from a "User" to an "Admin".

On the documentation it says:
"The code below can be used to grant admin status to the current user."

```
current_user.update_attribute :admin, true
```

But where would this snippet go? 
Here is the documentation, The admin role creation info is near the bottom of the page.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Add-an-Admin-Role

Comment: This likely will go into the action of a controller.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to the solution! Nothing like reading through the documentation :-)

By going with Option 2 mentioned on the wikipage, users in your application will be classified 
as 'regular' or 'admin', based on the admin attribute. The wikipage gives you the code for granting admin role to the current user, and leaves the decision of where to call this code up to you.

Fair enough, since how users become Admins is specific to each application, depending on how the users want it to be done.

One way to do it would be to have a 'Grant Current User Admin Rights' action in the GUI which would invoke the code. In that case, the code would go within a 'grant_current_user_admin_rights' method in the 'users_controller.rb' file. Of course, the views and the routes should be modified accordingly as well.

You could call that code from `after_create` callback on the user model, **ensuring all users become Admins** :-)

Another way to do it would be to set the admin flag for specific users either in the console or through database seeds.

Example from a seeds file on one of my projects:

```
admin_user = User.new( :email => USER_EMAIL, :password => PASSWORD_STRING, :name => USER_NAME )
admin_user.admin = true
admin_user.save!
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

4 years late but the true answer to OPs question, when he asked where to put:

> current_user.update_attribute :admin, true

can be solved by going to the terminal/command prompt.

Type in

> rails c

to access the rails terminal.

then go to your user, and since you're probably the first it'll be:

> user = User.find(1)
>
> user.update_attribute(:admin, true)

Assuming you followed all the previous steps in Option 2 of the documentation, this will set your user to have a true Admin attribute.

You can verify this by going

> User.find(1)
> and it should say "admin: true" at the end of the big block of text.